# C# Regex to find section number ,with no special character after it

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Regex -> `^([\s]*(?i)(section)[\s]*(?=[xvi])M*D?C{0,4}L?x{0,4}v{0,4}i{0,4})[\s]?`

Text -> `Section VII, some text.....`

This regex matches Section VII and Section VII(space). 
But it should not match "Section VII," , as after the match there is one special character.

Comment: Do you mean there must be a space or end of string? Try [`(?i)^(\s*(section)\s*(?=[xvi])M*D?C{0,4}L?x{0,4}v{0,4}i{0,4})(?!\S)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%5e%28%5cs*%28section%29%5cs*%28%3f%3d%5bxvi%5d%29M*D%3fC%7b0%2c4%7dL%3fx%7b0%2c4%7dv%7b0%2c4%7di%7b0%2c4%7d%29%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=Section+VII%2c+some+text%0d%0aSection+VII+and+more+text%0d%0aSection+VII&o=m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [zero-width negative lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^([\s]*(?i)(section)[\s]*(?=[xvi])M*D?C{0,4}L?x{0,4}v{0,4}i{0,4})(?!\S)
```

The critical part is `(?!\S)`, which means that no (`!`) non-whitespace character (`\S`) should be at the end. It's a zero-width expression, which means that the character itself (if any) won't be a part of your match.

Comment: @Downvoter: Feedback would be appreciated.